# Is name a reserved word in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Can I name a column `name` in my mysql tables?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why not just try it?

```
mysql> select name from name;
+------+
| name |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

Also you can quote any names with ``.

```
mysql> select `from` from `from`;
+------+
| from |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

Comment: Nothing like simply trying it out!

Comment: To answer the OP's title question, the documentation states that `name` is a MySQL keyword, i.e. it has a meaning in SQL, but it's not a _reserved_ keyword so you can use it without wrapping it in backticks.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 5):

You should be fine calling a column 'name'.  Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html for more details on how to deal with reserved words.

Wrapping column names in the (`) character ensures that even reserved words won't be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of whether or not you *can*, you might want to consider *why* you want to do it in the first place. Name of what? What kind of name? After a few years, if you look at the database schema, will you still remember these details?

I suggest it would be in your best interest to treat the column name the same as you would treat any variable names, and give it a descriptive name. Years down the road, you (or anyone who maintains your code) will be thanking you.

Comment: Well, a column called 'name' in the 'companies' table would be fairly self explanatory...

Comment: @ceejayoz No, it would not. full_name would be. Because typically people have a first and a last name. Sometimes even a middle name. So name is not at all that self explanatory.

Comment: @Till If the table is named **`companies`** (as stated in my comment) I probably wouldn't expect it to be full of people records. I'd probably expect it to be full of company records, which don't have a first and last name. If I wanted to double-check, I could look at a few rows.

Comment: @ceejayoz You can do many things. But what about a new dev using your code. Does he have access to production databases with records? Maybe, maybe not. My thoughts are that you are assuming too much. And in the end. When you say, "Well he could look into the database.", then you should know the code is wrong. He shouldn't have to. I shouldn't run anything to know what it does. Not easy, but that's the objective.

Comment: Again, a column named "name" in a "companies" table is, I'd say, perfectly understandable to any reasonable person.

Comment: In fact, it would be *more* confusing to call it `full_name`, because then you'd expect the company to have a "short name" or something. And if it doesn't, you're left scratching your head. Awesome.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes** even though if its a person name I would recommend *FirstName* or *FullName* to be the column name to be more specific [MYSQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: The link here is 404 not found

Answer (score 1):

Just a word of caution here. As field name `name` is fine.

However in stored procedures name as **variable** does something else.

Consider the following procedure. When I called this procedure it always would alter the first record in my config database. Once I renamed the variable named name to something else, things worked fine.

```
PROCEDURE `updateConfig`(IN name VARCHAR(255), IN val VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY `config`
  SET `value`=val
  WHERE `name` = name
  LIMIT 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE mytest (name INT);

SELECT  *
FROM    mytest;

name
--------
```

In dubious cases you may enclose names into grave accents:

```
CREATE TABLE `CREATE TABLE` (name INT);

SELECT  *
FROM    `CREATE TABLE`;

name
--------
```