# unknown column in where case

Tags: mysql

```
Client(ID_Client,Name,Surname,number)
Ticket(ID_Ticket,ID_Client,Problem)
```

and two variables that come from a html form (`name` and `surname`)

I'm doing a simple query that search the `ID_Client` in the table `client` with `name` and `surname`
in my php page ( http://phpserver.hensemberger.it/~d2nastasi/Vivaio/Vivaio/Prenotazioni.html ):

```
$db=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pwd")or die(mysql_error());
$sel=mysql_select_db("d2") or die(mysql_error());
$name=$_POST['name'];
$surname=$_POST['surname'];  //this two variables arrives with no problem

$query="SELECT ID_Client FROM Client WHERE Name={$name}
AND Surname = {$surname} ";


$ris=mysql_query($query)or die (mysql_error()); //stops here
$array=mysql_fetch_array($ris);

print($array['ID_Client']);
```

---

the problem is that he stops $ris=.....  saying as error

Unknown column 'simone' in 'where clause'

Comment: Check this question here, looks same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738124/is-name-a-reserved-word-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

You need to put quotes around string literals in SQL.

```
select * from table where name = 'Carl' and lastname = 'Smith';
```

Additionally, it's not safe to build a query from raw user-inputted variables (such as POST). Use something like `mysql_real_escape_string()` before you pass it into the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't quoting your `where` values:

`$query="SELECT ID_Client FROM Client WHERE Name='{$name}' AND Surname = '{$surname}'";`

MySQL is getting confused, thinking you want rows where the Surname column is the same as the non-existent Simone column, but you want it to match that absolute value, hence you need the quotes.