# How to select 2 data from 1 column based on other relations in other table

Tags: sql, select

Say, I have a table like the following called "name":

```
| nid | name   |
----------------
| 1   | john   | 
| 2   | mike   | 
| 3   | tom    |
| 4   | jack   |
| 5   | will   |
| 6   | david  | ...
```

and another table like the following called "relation_father_son":

```
| rid | fnid | snid |
---------------------
| 1   |    1 |    2 |
| 2   |    1 |    3 |
| 3   |    4 |    5 |
| 4   |    2 |    6 | ...
```

then I would like a result like the following:

```
| father | son   |
------------------
| john   | mike  |
| john   | tom   |
| jack   | will  |
| mike   | david | ...
```

What the should the SQL query be?

Comment: I tried, but seems the content of tables are in the same line...no <return>, it would looks very wired...

Comment: OK, let me try more. Thanks, Strom.

Comment: Also, include what you have attempted so far

Comment: @Andreas, normally I would agree, this is not a coding service, but, for a simple self joined query, the solution is very hard to properly ask a search engine for information on how to do it.

Comment: `name` is a poor table name. Call it `persons` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query would be:

```
SELECT 
  f.name AS father, 
  s.name AS son
FROM relation_father_son 
INNER JOIN name AS f 
  ON (nid = fnid)
INNER JOIN name AS s 
  ON (nid = snid)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is confusing that the first table is named as `name`. You should rename it to a more distinguished name, such as `family_names`. Read more at: [Is name a reserved word in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738124/is-name-a-reserved-word-in-mysql)

For the desired result, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT `name` FROM `family_names` WHERE nid=fnid) AS father, 
  (SELECT `name` FROM `family_names` WHERE nid=snid) AS son 
FROM relation_father_son
```

Comment: According to ANSI SQL, `name` is not reserved. (Still a poor table name...)

Comment: Yes, I didn't say it's a reserved word, but a confusing one.

Comment: It is not really my database, just an example. Whatever, your comment reminds me to choose reasonable table name and column name to avoid confusing, Thank you, Raptor. :)